# Random numbers from physical sources on the Internet

Tags: random

What are the addresses of some websites that offers random numbers from physical sources? I'm looking both for free services and services that cost money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HotBits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/):

- Genuine random numbers, generated by radioactive decay.
- HotBits are generated by timing successive pairs of radioactive decays detected by a Geiger-Müller tube interfaced to a computer.
- Once the random bytes are delivered to you, they are immediately discarded—the same data will never be sent to any other user and no records are kept of the data at this or any other site.

[Secure Server HotBits Request](https://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/secure_generate.html)

Answer (score 4):

I have been using [http://www.random.org/](http://random.org/), and i like it. Generates random numbers from atmospheric noise, and also is capable of generate:

- coin flips
- dice rolling
- card shuffling

among others, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the [Quantum Random Bit Generator](http://random.irb.hr/) may be of use ? It relies on photonic emission in semiconductors and the detection thereof by photoelectric effect.

They supply command line and library/API access via various different platforms/frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux systems have a `/dev/random` device built in.  That provides random numbers from physical sources.

> The random number generator gathers
>   environmental noise from device
>   drivers and other sources into an
>   entropy pool

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urandom

Comment: The entropy pool is based on physical sources.  Sounds really random to me.

Comment: It's slow. You can only get a few random characters per second. Might not be enough for certain needs.

Comment: The entropy pool is based on a variety of physical factors that are not easily controlled, but it is still deterministic - if you know the set of inputs to the system (keypress intervals, timing information, etc) then you can predict the next bit from the previous bits.  There are many essays on random numbers which go into detail using statistical analysis, and for most uses and most people /dev/urandom would be fine, but it is not considered a cryptographically secure source of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[www.Random.org](http://www.Random.org)

Apparently they use Atmospheric noise to generate they're numbers though I'm not sure if they've published their algorithms.