# What sources can produce random data

Tags: algorithm, random, statistics

Here are some. What are some other?

```
* timing of radioactive decays
* recording background noise into .wav files
* live video files
* session logs from chat lines
* keystroke latencies for typed text
```

Comment: Your question might be better (and on-topic) if it asked how to create a truly random (and not pseudo-random) numeric sequence inside a computer.  Actually, that question has been asked several times already; see here: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=1113&q=create+truly+random+numbers+site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Comment: [dice rolls](http://xkcd.com/221/ "dice rolls")

Comment: @user521180: it depends on your definition of randomness ;)  I mean, at one point it becomes some kind of a metaphysical question!

Comment: From the "Related" sidebar: [Random numbers from physical sources on the Internet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/782210/2509) for sources of such numbers ready-made; [Generating totally random numbers without random function?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3834102/2509) a duplicate of [True random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37702/2509). Not a duplicate as such, but most of the answers have been discussed in these and other questions already.

Comment: @SpoonBender It really doesn't. It's simply a matter of clearly defining what you want.

Comment: The trickier part is measuring entropy.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: it really does...

Comment: There's nothing "metaphysical" about asking about sources of random data. It's well defined in information theory - see shannon information, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Mouse movements
- Soil moisture
- Number of ants passing through a point in an antfarm.
- Checksum/hash of data from the frontpage of a very dynamic website (like twitter).

Answer (score 2):

The nice [**random.org**](http://www.random.org) site by Mads Haahr has been providing hardware RNG draws via a web interface for many years.

My [**random**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=random) package for [**R**](http://www.r-project.org) uses this:

```
R> library(random)
R> rn <- randomNumbers(100, 1, 100, 5)
R> head(rn)
     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
[1,] 96 99 68 95 90
[2,] 84 11 62 20 40
[3,] 83 79 38 32 90
[4,] 28 18 32 58 97
[5,] 15 31 42 68 98
[6,] 65 93  6 15 55
R> rs <- randomSequence(1, 20)
R> head(rs)
     V1
[1,] 14
[2,]  4
[3,]  6
[4,] 11
[5,] 13
[6,] 20
R>
```

There is ample documentation in an [introduction by Mads](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/random/vignettes/random-essay.pdf) which I include with the package

Comment: Those numbers are exactly the ones I predicted.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript creates its "random" numbers from an internal clock in milliseconds, which is quite random. Other sources may include atmospheric pressure and public keys.

Comment: JS random numbers (and most the 'random' call in pretty much any language) are pseudo-random number generators (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), not truly random.  And how are 'public keys' a source of random data?

Comment: Clocks are random now? I'll have to remember that next time I'm late.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

In short - best random sources are such those roots are based on laws of quantum mechanics or chaos theory.